# OleDB Provider for Oracle not found in in Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, oracle, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I'm deploying a small ASP.NET (framework 3.5) application in a Windows Server Web 2008 32 bits, IIS 7. The applications needs connection to an Oracle DB in another Server, using the tradicional DataAdapter, Oracle Connection, etc.

I´ve installed correctly the Oracle Client in the server (the server is another server´s client) and I´ve checked that this server has access to the server where the database is.

Even though my app isn´t able to connect to DataBase. The message says that Oracle components haven´t been found. It doesn´t find the OleDB Provider for Oracle or some dll.

¿Something I shluod know about permissions of the ASP.NEt users or something like this?

Some idea??

Thanks in advance.

Gus.

Comment: can you establish a connection through - sql+, Toad or Sqldeveloper and what is the specific error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the path. It could be that the Oracle client directory is not on the path of the account that runs your ASPNET app.

Actually there are other steps you can go through, to verify the Oracle client install.

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2006/03/17/connecting-asp-net-2-0-gridview-to-oracle.aspx) is old but may be helpful.